# Google data (gdata) in eclipse with app engine, java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gdata-api

Ive had a similar question as this one before, and when that solved this came. So here we go again.

The content of doGet pretty much works but when I try it as a part of a servlet that eclipse created for me I get errors. Its looks a bit like I don't have the appropriate files referenced in the library, but I think I do.

The java code looks like this:

```
package picasatest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.google.gdata.client.photos.PicasawebService;
import com.google.gdata.data.photos.AlbumEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.photos.UserFeed;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PicasaTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");

    try {
        PicasawebService service = new PicasawebService("Picasa test");
        service.setUserCredentials("username@gmail.com", "password");
        URL feedURL = new URL("http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/username?kind=album");
        UserFeed feed = service.getFeed(feedURL, UserFeed.class);
        for (AlbumEntry entry : feed.getAlbumEntries()) {
             System.out.println(entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I have referenced to google-collect-1.0-rc2.jar, mail.jar, activation.jar, servlet-api.jar, gdata-client.jar, gdata-client-meta.jar, gdata-core.jar, gdata-media.jar, gdata-photos-2.0.jar and gdata-photos-meta-2.0.jar according to instruction from [google](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/eclipse.html). Is there anything else I have to do for it to work?

And I get this error to the console:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/photos/PicasawebService
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2357)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:321)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:303)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:124)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:54)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:313)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:830)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

Any idea on what I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jason Parekh from the Google group "Google App Engine for Java"

> Where is your GData client JAR located?  It should be in the war/WEB-INF/lib 
>   directory for it to be included in the packaged war file. 
>   jason

So your not supposed to put the whole gdata folder in war/WEB-INF like i did...
Problem solved

Comment: Had the same problem... it was killing me... let me see if it works or not.

Comment: and in Android? Cause I have the same issue?