# NoClassDefFoundError when using Google Spreadsheets APIs on Google Application Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets

I followed the instructions as listed in [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), and things compile Ok.
However, when I try to run the application on App engine, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdata/client/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetService
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
```

I see others seem to have faced similar issues as well
 [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps/general-discussion/1ILYKJbtW1E%5B1-25%5D).

I thought it might be an incompatibility and tried upgrading my AppEngine SDK to 1.7.0 and GWT SDK to 2.4.0 as well but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add all required jars to your library dir? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#setting_up_your_client_library

Comment: Of course. Did a small test as a standalone app and that works fine as well. It's definitely some App engine issue!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223969/google-data-gdata-in-eclipse-with-app-engine-java

Comment: This explains which jars to add.. https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/java/retrieving_gdata_feeds#configure

Comment: .. and how to edit build path: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Comment: I'll make that into an answer then.

Comment: My jar is gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar, (which is not one listed in the above link), but adding it to the war/WEB-INF/lib dir worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, [add appropriate jars](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/java/retrieving_gdata_feeds#configure),

second, [edit your Eclipse build path](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).